# Should these images be hosted on imgur?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

In [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9003/556) there is:

> As for how much of the fuselage is taken up by fuel tanks, you can look at cutaways of the [KC-135][3] and [KC-10][4] *(unfortunately the captions for the KC-10 are in a foreign language, as I could not find a high-enough resolution one in English)*

Should these images be inline the answer (i.e. shown as images not hyperlinks) -- or more importantly, at least copied to and hosted on SE's imgur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at least copied to and hosted on SE's imgur?

only if the original copyright allows it.

Comment: So I gather that you don't assume that doing so is fair use? The reason I was suggesting copying them was, of course, in case (or eventually "when") the hyperlinks break, and the images are integral to the answer. Being images I guess they won't be in the wayback machine.

Comment: @ChrisW sometimes I find images in the wayback machine, but yeah, I share your worry about images disappearing and thus "breaking" the answers. IIRC copyright is the reason we stopped embedding/reuploading images from certain websites (e.g. airliners .net)